# Using OpenALPR C# wrapper

Tags: c#, opencv, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I am currently working on automatic licence plate recognition program using the OpenALPR Library found [here](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr). I would like to take advantage of the C# wrappers available for the library. However when I attempt to compile the example application found in [src/bindings/csharp/](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/tree/master/src/bindings/csharp) it compiles with the following errors:

> Error 5   Metadata file 'openalpr-net.dll' could not be found
>
> Error 2   error C1083: Cannot open include file:'opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp': No such file or directory
>
> Error 3   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp': No such file or directory
>
> Error 4   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp': No such file or directory

I understand i have some missing dependencies, however could someone point me to where i can get these dependencies and where to put them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)